# How to get chromiumwebbrowser html document?

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I want to know if there is an html file linked with chromiumwebbrowser.

When using IE-based webbrowser, I used webbrowser.document.

After importing the document, we checked whether the content was null or not and checked the existence of html.

```
if(webbrowser.Document != null) {...}
```

How can I get this to work on chromium?

I'm using chromiumWebbrowser.

```
private ChromiumWebBrowser browser;
```

Comment: You can get the source as a string,  there is no Document object like you are referring.

Comment: Also it would be helpful if you detailed what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to execute a script through ExecuteScriptAsync only when the html file exists. I would think html exists if there is source code. thanks

Comment: How exactly are you loading empty html pages? What do you mean by `exists`? You will get a `404` in the normal course of events. Please provide more detail.

Comment: I put some javascript based html file in the browser.                                    
"browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser (" test.html ");"
If test.html enters the browser , it will not return null and it is exist.
I am a foreigner and I am not sure about the meaning. please understand.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. What is an actual example of a `Url` you are using? Based on the very vaigue details I'd try http://cefsharp.github.io/api/75.1.x/html/E_CefSharp_IWebBrowser_FrameLoadEnd.htm which is only called when a frame successfully loads, each page has at least one frame, the main frame.

Comment: Also if you are loading Local files from disk, then just check the content before you load them into the browser, be much simpler. If you require further assistance please **edit** your question and provide more detail, a sample of the `Url`, the code you have so far etc.

Comment: Thanks. I solved my problem by using FrameLoadEnd.

Answer (score -1):

Ima so sorry, old post was wrong.
You cant acces the html document like in default Visual Studio web browser, but you can execute scripts inside document by ChromiumWebBrowser.ExecuteScriptAsync($"document.///somecode///") function.

Example code:

```
 ChromiumWebBrowser.ExecuteScriptAsync($"document.getElementsByName('examplename')[0].value='example';");
```